# How to split a string after a certain sequence of characters in PHP

Tags: php, string

In PHP I have a string, for example:
"http://localhost:8888/Web_api_bachelor/public/uploads/images/image1.png"

I want to split this string, so I get a new string that starts after the "uploads/" part in the original string. So the new string is "images/image1.png".

How do I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: So what have you tried already? Are you struggling to find where "uploads/" is in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is where [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) comes in handy.

```
$string = "http://localhost:8888/Web_api_bachelor/public/uploads/images/image1.png";

echo strstr($string, "uploads");
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

$result = end(explode('uploads/', $string));
where $string is the input;

Comment: For explanation: Explode  splits the string into an array at the point where it matches 'uploads/' in the string, and end gets the final element of that.